# How to get initial params into jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to get params which i declared into web.xml.
This code fragment is from `web.xml` :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>test</param-name>
        <param-value>testValue</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to get ones by this code:

```
<%= getServletContext().getInitParameter("test") %><%= application.getInitParameter("test") %><%= "Param = " + application.getInitParameter("test") %>
```

but i never got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that, you are using a scriptlet which is not good code practise.You should avoid using them.Use servlet for doing such things.Java scriptlets have been obsolete and discredited since the introduction of JSP 2.0 and there are many good reasons not to use Java scriptlets in JSPs.

And one more thing your code is correct for getting values from servlet context. You probably have problem s web.xml

Change your web.xml.Change your url pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And you can get this va lue as you have written code to get value or by simply `<%=config.getInitParameter("test")%>`

Comment: Thanks. I only start to use Java EE. But i didn't understand wherein is my mistake? Why i can't use <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern> ?

Comment: Url-pattern specifies the type of urls for which, the servlet given in servlet-name should be called.You want to call your servlet for index.jsp page . /Index is not a valid url. Thats why.And its my answer which is correct if I am not wrong ;)

Comment: Hope you got your answer . /index was not a valid url.url-pattern means that wtever request comes for this url should go through defined servlet-name servlet.

Answer (score 1):

To get servlet init parameter , don't call `getServletContext().getInitParameter()` which will return a **context parameter** , but you have to call :

```
<%= getServletConfig().getInitParameter("test") %>
```

or simply

```
<%= config.getInitParameter("test") %>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Even like this: <% out.println("<br>"); out.println(getInitParameter("testParam")); %>

Comment: I have one problem. When i invoke my page like this "localhost:8080/MyWebPage/index.jsp" then i dont take changes, but i invoke my page like this "localhost:8080/MyWebPage/index.jsp" then i get the initial params. What is the problem?  PS Sorry for my english... I hope that i explained clearly...

Comment: did you mean "localhost:8080/MyWebPage/index.jsp" and "localhost:8080/MyWebPage/index" ? where the second one doesn't have .jsp ??

Comment: Yes. I have only one index.jsp, but for some reason GlassFish have two instance of my page. Maybe I something did not correctly into the web.xml? This is full code of web.xml:

Comment: <div> <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>testParam</param-name>
            <param-value>testValue</param-value>
        </init-param>        
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping></div>

Comment: @greenpo1son you need to replace <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern> to /index.jsp..

Comment: It works. But what was my problem? I only start to learn Java EE.

Comment: I have  answered that question .Your code was correct , your web.xml was not.Did't you try that?

Comment: I tried. I just changed <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>.

Answer (score 0):

Dont define every jsp as a servlet. There still is a jsp servlet that will handle this for you. If you need application wide variables use "context-param". Better avoid "global" variables unless they are changing on every server. Create a properties file and read them from there using ResourceBundle.